# How do I prevent an error when someone enters invalid characters into my scanner.nextInt()?

Tags: java

I am new to java and am currently making a business simulator that runs like a text based game. I want the player to be able to input how much they want to pay their employees per hour, but I am sure that someone will either try putting letters into the input or maybe accidentally hit a key while trying to enter a number. This gives me an error, and I am unsure of how to prevent stuff like this from happening.

I have tried creating a method that takes the entire line of input, number or letters, and gets rid of every character except numbers, but this could be inaccurate and is very inconvenient.

Comment: look into the exception handling topic

Answer (score 1):

Use try catch

```
try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextInt());
            System.out.println(scanner.nextInt() + " is a valid integer number");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextInt() + " is not a valid integer number");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `try catch`, the exception you're looking for is `InputMismatchException`:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        scanner.nextInt();
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```